# RETRACTED - Netplan does not add the interface to the bridge as defined

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, netplan

## Conclusion: I retract this question.

Well, the bad news is I started running into (seemingly unrelated) IO errors on my hard drive. After some troubleshooting, the drive seems completely dead; I can't even boot it anymore.

The good news is, I installed Ubuntu Server on a new hard drive, and the configuration I posted below works just fine. My best guess is the old hard drive was not launching something properly (although I did search various logs and found nothing). So we'll never know. I'm happy it's working so simply now, but frustrated we wasted so much time on what was likely just a hardware issue.

Thank you all for your help! At least I learned a lot about Netplan.

## Original post

I'm using a Ubuntu 22.04.3 (Ubuntu Server) with KVM installed on a mini computer with two physical NICs. I want to take the second physical NIC and apply it to a bridge so the KVM virtual machines can be exposed to the network. The problem is, my second physical interface (`eno2`) doesn't come up by default, nor does it associate itself with the bridge (`br0`).

Here is my configuration file `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: true
    eno2:
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eno2]
      dhcp4: false
      parameters:
        stp: false
        forward-delay: 0
```

I can make it work via the command line. To make everything work exactly the way I want it, I just need to execute the following commands:

```
$ sudo brctl addif br0 eno2   # add eno2 to the bridge br0.
$ sudo ip link set br0 up     # bring up both interfaces.
$ sudo ip link set eno2 up
$ sudo dhclient br0           # ask the bridge to request an IP again.
```

What am I doing wrong to make this configuration not start working at boot time?

ChatGPT thinks there's a bug in Netplan. :grin:

## Debugging data

Output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1d.1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
       logical name: eno1
       version: 11
       serial: 00:01:c0:33:4a:5e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt-fd 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=st_gmac driverversion=Jan_2016 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.26 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:130 memory:6001340000-600137ffff
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1d.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
       logical name: eno2
       version: 11
       serial: 00:01:c0:33:4a:5f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=intel-eth-pci latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:170 memory:6001300000-600133ffff
```

### Clue 1 (2023-09-27)

There are files for `eno1` and `eno2` here: `/run/systemd/network/10-netplan-eno2.network`, and the only difference is that `eno2` has a section:

```
[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no
```

I can delete this (or change it to "yes"), and it's back on reboot. It's back if I run `sudo netplan apply`. And running `sudo networkctl reload` doesn't seem to change anything at all.

### Clue 2 (2023-09-27)

When I run `sudo networkctl renew eno2`, I get this:

```
Failed to renew dynamic configuration of interface eno2: Interface eno2 is not managed by systemd-networkd
```

If I run `sudo networkctl renew eno1`, I get no error. Suspicious, right? Why isn't `eno2` managed by networkd?

Comment: Your netplan says dhcp: false for br0 and also doesn't specify any static IPs.  Have you tried dhcp: true on br0?

Comment: @slangasek Yep, I've tried enabling DHCP for `br0`. I presume this part doesn't work only because `eno2` isn't attached to `br0`. And actually, I should probably point out that I don't actually need to get an IP for `br0`, which is why it's not in the config. It was mostly an exercise to see that attaching `eno2` was working as expected after manually configuring it.

Comment: What do you see in `sudo lshw -c network` ?

Comment: @jtessier72 Thanks for the interest. I added the output to my question.

Comment: After you edited your Netplan YAML file, did you run `sudo netplan generate` and `sudo netplan apply`?

Comment: @mpboden Yes. Many, many times. :) I do notice a change in behavior when I modify the file (i.e. remove the bridge), so I know it's trying.

Comment: I created a VM and used your exact Netplan configuration with the exception of interface names. It works and survives a reboot. So that doesn’t appear to be the issue. Did you ever install Network Manager? If so, that could be a conflict. Otherwise, some configuration is preventing the interface from enabling, thus preventing the bridge from being created.

Comment: @mpboden, oh that's an interesting data point! The output of `sudo systemctl status NetworkManager` is "Unit NetworkManager.service could not be found." This is a clean version of Ubuntu Server, so I don't expect it's anything I did. What distribution/version did you use?

Comment: Try to add an empty config for the interface`eno2: {}` - I believe that brings it up without an IP. Found this here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037276/bring-up-but-dont-assign-address-with-netplan

Comment: @jtessier72 I tried it, but it didn't change anything. I'm fairly sure this whole issue is something to do with `eno2` not being started properly. Even if I remove the bridge entirely, `eno2` doesn't come UP at boot. I added two "Clue" sections to my question.

Comment: Can you update question with output of `journalctl -b0 | grep eno2`?

Comment: @mpboden Sorry for the disappointing update (see above), but I wasn't able to run that command before the hard drive failed. I appreciate the help from everyone. For what it's worth, I know I did run `journalctl` and the output seemed sane, but I didn't save it.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is not essential to have the bridge available during boot process I would setup a bash script that enables the bridge.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
brctl addif br0 eno2
ip link set br0 up
ip link set eno2 up
dhclient br0
```

Then you can create a timer that executes the enable bridge script 10 seconds after boot has finished.

There might be more elegant solutions, but this solution will do the job.

Comment: That's true, and that's probably what I'll have to do eventually. I'd add `/etc/systemd/system/eno2-br0-fix.service` (for example) and execute that script after the network starts. But I'm trying to set this system up to be very simple to tear down and set up again, and it annoys me that I have to add all this extra nonsense to fix a problem that seems like a fairly basic configuration.